# Connections between Bounds in MIPs

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, branch-and-bound

we are currently learning about MIP/MILP minimization at university and have become familiar with the branch-and-bound algorithm. Unfortunately, the relationship between upper bound, lower bound and dual bound (as shown [here](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/8265539575953-What-is-the-MIPGap)) is not clear to me, nor what the optimality gap is, or when a MIP can be solved optimally.

Answer (score 4):

For a minimization problem, the **lower** bound arises from the linear programming relaxation and is also called a *dual bound*, and the **upper** bound arises from a feasible solution and is also called a *primal bound*.  That situation matches the linked picture.

For a maximization problem, the **upper** bound arises from the linear programming relaxation and is also called a *dual bound*, and the **lower** bound arises from a feasible solution and is also called a *primal bound*.

The definition of optimality gap varies by solver and can be confusing to interpret when the bounds have opposite sign, but the general metric is a nonnegative ratio:
$$\frac{\text{upper bound} - \text{lower bound}}{\epsilon+\text{absolute value of either lower bound or upper bound}},$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small positive constant to avoid division by $0$.  The idea is that the gap decreases to $0$ as the solver finds better bounds, so it is a measure of progress toward optimally solving the problem.  Most solvers allow you to set an optimality tolerance as a termination criterion so the solver will stop when it finds a feasible solution that is provably within that optimality gap.